# two Intents in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

In my mainActivity I have two Intents and in my content_main.xml I have two Buttons.
When I click the first Button(openKriterien) it opens the Activity I want.
But when I click the second Button(openMeinepp) it does'nt open the other Activity.- It crashes :(
Did I something wrong ?

```
public void openKriterien(View view1) {

    Intent openKriterienIntent = new Intent(this,Kriterien.class);

    final int ergebnis1 = 1;
    startActivity(openKriterienIntent);
}
public void openMeinepp(View view2) {
    Intent openMeineppIntent = new Intent(this,Meinepp.class);

    final int ergebnis2 = 1;
    startActivity(openMeineppIntent);
}
```

Comment: *"Did I something wrong ?"* apparently. Post your stacktrace from the crash and we can help you figure out what

Comment: Can you post your crash log so we can able to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. Confirm that you have declared this Meinepp activity in Your Manifest.xml file.